# How to forward packet with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables

I need to forward the packet from ppp0, then forward to another server, how to do this, thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: thanks!  I need to forward packets from one PPTP server(ip is 172.17.0.10 and interface is ppp0) to  another server (10.10.10.10 eth1), then I can capture the packet on 10.10.10.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp0  -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x

Comment: but it gave me an error: Bad argument '10.10.10.10' :(

Comment: -j DNAT --to <ip address to forawrd traffic>

Answer (score 0):

iptables does not forward packets, the routing engine does (to be configured with `ip route`).